# C# class automatically calls its method

Tags: c#, class

Recently I was browsing one C# program and stumbled across some weird behavior of a class inside of it. I wrote a little program to outline this behavior:

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            Test inst1 = new Test();

            inst1.name0 = "Hello";
            inst1.name1 = "World";

            Console.WriteLine(inst1.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine(inst1);
        }
    }

    class Test
    {
        public string name0;
        public string name1;

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return string.Format("Name0: {0}; Name1: {1}", name0 ?? "(null)", name1 ?? "(null)");
        }
    }
```

Output:

```
Name0: Hello; Name1: World
Name0: Hello; Name1: World
```

So why do inst1.ToString() and inst1 return the same value in WriteLine() method? I'm confused.

Comment: [If `Console.Writeline` has an object parameter, it calls that object's `ToString` method.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/swx4tc5e(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Since the class overrides the ToString() method,Console.WriteLine() will call ToString() in the second instance of Console.WriteLine() so therefore you get the same results.

Comment: If you call `ToString()`, it will take the result of that. If you do not call it, the `WriteLine` method will call it for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When passed an object, the `Console.WriteLine` overload will use the object's `ToString` method.

[From the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/swx4tc5e(v=vs.110).aspx),

> If value is null, only the line terminator is written. Otherwise, the ToString method of value is called to produce its string representation, and the resulting string is written to the standard output stream.

Comment: It only applies for Console.WriteLine method?

Comment: There are other cases where this happens, such as string interpolation/`string.Format`

Answer (score 1):

This happens because the Test class overrides the ToString function.

When Console.Writeline has to display a non String object, it will look for the ToString function and use it if available.